# Python thread in while loop

Tags: python

I want `test_func` to work separately. It should print every N seconds, I've tried this, but time.sleep() just stops my program.

```
import time
import threading

def test_func():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Printing stuff....")
    t = threading.Timer(10, test_func).start()

test_func()

# something goes here constantly
```

So I though of doing something like this, but that doesn't work either.

```
import time
import threading

def test_func():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Printing stuff....")

# something goes here constantly

while True:
    t = threading.Timer(10, test_func).start()
```

So, how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a timer for this. Just put your function in a thread, so:

```
def test_func():
    while True:
        print("Printing stuff....")
        time.sleep(10)

threading.Thread(target=test_func).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not span more threads within while loop. Instead change code to

```
def test_func():
    while True:
              time.sleep(10)
              print("Printing stuff....")
```

Call the test_func() here in thread.